# Load Factor in Hash Table

Tags: load, hashtable

The type of a hash table H under closed addressing is an array of list references, and under
open addressing is an array of keys. Assume a key requires one “word” of memory and a
linked list node requires two words, one for the key and one for a list reference. Consider each
of these load factors for closed addressing: 0.5, 1.0, 2.0.
Estimate the total space requirement, including space for lists, under closed addressing, and
then, assuming that the same amount of space is used for an open addressing hash table,
what are the corresponding load factors under open addressing?

I only know that the formula for load factor = No. of entries entered/ Hash Table Size

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have N elements to store using closed addressing.

- At load factor 0.5, we have N / 0.5 = 2N buckets, each being 1-word
  list references.  Plus, we know there are N nodes storing values and
  further list-references (needing 1 word each), so another 2N words.
  Total = 4N words.
- At load factor 1, we only have N buckets, so the memory comes down to N + 2N = 3N words.
- At load factor 2, we have 0.5N words for buckets, and still 2N for elements/list-references, so 2.5N words in total.

With open addressing, if we had 4N words to use and N elements, our load factor would be 1/4 = 0.25.  With 3N words, 1/3 ~= 0.33.  With 2.5N, 1/2.5 = .4.